# Infinitely tiling the contents of a draggable DIV without duplicating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a map that is divided into 800x800 150 pixel tiles. These tiles are contained within a jQuery draggable wrapper, which moves the contents of the tiles around inside the parent to achieve a Google Maps style dragging effect. The top left corner is 0,0 and the bottom right is 799x799. I am looking to replicate Google's tiling effect where the user can drag to the left or top of the start point or the right or bottom of the end point and see the tiled (repeated) contents of the DIV in a seamless manner. Using Clone is not an option as it creates duplicates of an already very large (albeit not yet optimised) source which seriously hampered the load times of the page when dragging was performed.

I could best summarise this by saying I need the map itself to have the visual effect and user experience of looping endlessly, but actually only using one instance of the map source. The resulting effect would not be too dissimilar to the repeating background of an image on a page, except with the contents of the map DIV and not an image. When the user drags the map left of anything on the 0 X Axis, it should display X 799, X 798, etc.

I have not had any luck searching for a solution. Is such an effect possible? If so, what would I need to use to achieve it? I am content with simple answers to point me in the right direction; I do not expect somebody to produce a working example that I can cut and paste. Not afraid to research and experiment myself, my problem is I really don't know where to start. I have plenty of experience with Javascript and jQuery but I've never had to do anything quite like this.

Comment: Cool idea man but... hum... where is the code?What have you done so far? What is the error?

Comment: I haven't provided the source of the map because I didn't feel it was relevant. All it would be is a DIV containing lots of DIVs, which would just clutter my question with code that isn't necessary or helps illustrate the point. The current jQuery I'm using handles the click events on the tiles to bring up relevant information boxes. I haven't coded most of the raw functionality yet because I'm thinking I will have to use Canvas instead if a jQuery solution isn't available. Right now I'm trying to establish if what I need to do is possible.